# How to handle Javascript depencencies after bundling?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

From what I understand, the common way to deploy a Javascript app is to take all your dependencies and put them all in one file (and then minify it). I don't understand how the code I wrote will then find the modules that are now all in this new file. I'm using node.js if that matters and use a gulp task like this to do the bundling:

```
gulp.task('bundle_deps', function() {
  return gulp.src('src/**/*.js')
    .pipe(concat('bundle.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(deploy_dir));
});
```

Comment: Just to clarify, you're trying to bundle and minify a node.js app?

Comment: Yes, I started out with an organic mess where all dependencies just worked through the magic of node.js and now I want to make a proper build environment for it. I'm just confused about how to reference the resulting bundle.js file.

Comment: You don't bundle node js apps because they're server side. You only bundle code that is going to run in the browser and node isn't made to run in the browser.

Comment: But I still need to make the server side dependencies available to the code running on the server. Are you saying I should simply copy my node_modules directory to the deployment directory?

Comment: yes usually you just copy the files to the server. Basically you can do a `git clone` and then you install all the dependencies (`npm install`, ...). then you just run the node app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about deployment, then the way to do this in node.js is to put your dependencies in the package.json file. For example:

```
{
  "name": "yourAppName",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "restify": ">= 2.6.0",
    "node-restify-validation": "0.0.6",
    "node-restify-swagger": "0.1.6"
  }
}
```

See: https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#dependencies

Then when you deploy the application, copy your code to the server and run the command

```
npm install
```

npm will read the dependencies in the package.json file and install them all for you.